# Using case when along with where in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have the following table. I need the SQL for amount of sales in 2016 in euros? I am trying the following code but I am getting syntax error!

```
Select 
    sum (quantity * price),
    case 
        when lower(currency) = pound 
            then set price = 1.1 * price
    end
from 
    order_items
where 
    year(order_date) = 2016;
```

Order_Items:

| order_item_key | order_key | order_date | customer_key | prime_status | quantity | price | currency |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xyz | ksp | 2020-06-01 | 123abc456 | 0 | 1 | 35 | pound |
| abc | sdl | 2019-08-15 | 567fjs290 | 1 | 2 | 2.3 | euro |
| wrt | ter | 2016-08-15 | 567fjs460 | 1 | 2 | 2.3 | euro |
| tyu | qwe | 2016-08-15 | 567fjs350 | 1 | 3 | 4.3 | euro |

Comment: A few things: (1) pound is a string, so you need to reference it as a string in your case statement. (2) You don't need to use "set price". 1.1*price is sufficient.

Comment: Isn't it a matter of quotes? At your 3rd line, you wrote: `when lower(currency) = pound then` and I assume you intended to put `when lower(currency) = "pound" then` with quotes around `pound`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is best done with a subquery. In the subquery, you first convert any 'pound' prices into Euros. The outer query computes the total 2016 sales in Euros.

```
select sum(quantity*euro_price) as euro_sales_2016
from (
    select quantity,
           case when lower(currency) = 'pound'
                then price * 1.1
                else price 
           end as euro_price
    from order_items 
    where YEAR(order_date) = 2016
) a;
```

Answer (score 0):

As written, `pound` is assumed to be a *column* - you need to quote it as a string literal.

Additionally, `case` is an *expression* that *returns* a value, `set` is not valid syntax.

```
Select sum(quantity*price) as total,
price * 
  case 
    when lower(currency) = 'pound' 
  then 1.1 else 1 end as rate
from order_items
where YEAR(order_date) = 2016;
```

Comment: A GROUP BY is needed too.